Condition for quadratic correction to first-order perturbation of metric
In Wald's book on General Relativity, the linearized Einstein tensor $G^{(1)}_{ab}$ can be obtained by substituting $g_{ab} = \eta_{ab} + \gamma_{ab}$ in the Einstein equation and ignoring terms that are of higher order than $1$ in $\gamma_{ab}$. We denote this linear-order Einstein tensor as $G^{(1)}_{ab}[\gamma_{cd}]$, where we explicitly show that the perturbation is $\gamma_{cd}$. In vacuum, where $T_{ab} = 0$, we obtain the first-order vacuum Einstein equation:
$$
G^{(1)}_{ab}[\gamma_{cd}] = 0 \tag{4.4.50}
$$
where the left hand side essentially consists of sums of second derivatives of a bunch of linear terms in $\gamma_{cd}$. When deriving the expression for the second order perturbation, where terms quadratic in $\gamma_{ab}$ are included, Wald first states that the quadratic terms of the Ricci tensor are:
$$
R^{(2)}_{ab} = \frac{1}{2}\gamma^{cd}\partial_a \partial_b \gamma_{cd} - \gamma^{cd} \partial_c \partial_{(a}\gamma_{b)d} \\
+\frac{1}{4}(\partial_a \gamma_{cd})\partial_{b}\gamma^{cd} + (\partial^d \gamma^c_b)\partial_{[d}\gamma_{c]a} \\
+\frac{1}{2}\partial_d(\gamma^{dc}\partial_c \gamma_{ab}) - \frac{1}{4}(\partial^c \gamma)\partial_c \gamma_{ab} \\
- (\partial_d \gamma^{cd} - \frac{1}{2}\partial^c \gamma)\partial_{(a}\gamma_{b)c} \tag{4.4.51}
$$
where $\gamma = \gamma^a_a$ and $\partial_a$ is the ordinary derivative operator. Furthermore, Wald now claims:

Thus, in order to maintain a solution of the vacuum Einstein equation to second order, we must correct $\gamma_{ab}$ by adding to it the term $\gamma_{ab}^{(2)}$, where $\gamma_{ab}^{(2)}$ satisfies:
$$
G^{(1)}_{ab}[\gamma^{(2)}_{cd}] + G^{(2)}_{ab}[\gamma_{cd}] = 0 \tag{4.4.52}
$$
where (in the case $R^{(1)}_{ab} = 0$) we have $G^{(2)}_{ab} = R^{(2)}_{ab} - \frac{1}{2}\eta_{ab}R^{(2)}$.

In an attempt to show this, I noted that if we assume that $G^{(1)}$ contains all linear terms and $G^{(2)}$ contains all quadratic terms, then the second order Einstein tensor must be the sum $G^{(1)} + G^{(2)}$. Hence I figured that in order for the new perturbation $\gamma_{cd} + \gamma^{(2)}_{cd}$ to fulfill the second order equation, we must have:
$$
G_{ab}^{(1)}[\gamma_{cd} + \gamma^{(2)}_{cd}] + G_{ab}^{(2)}[\gamma_{cd} + \gamma^{(2)}_{cd}] = 0 \tag{1}
$$
Since $G^{(1)}$ contains sums of derivatives linear in $\gamma_{ab}$ (essentially a bunch of terms $\sum \partial \partial \gamma$, informally speaking), it should be linear in the following sense:
$$
G^{(1)}_{ab}[\gamma_{cd} + \gamma^{(2)}_{cd}] = G^{(1)}_{ab}[\gamma_{cd}] + G^{(1)}_{ab}[\gamma^{(2)}_{cd}] = G^{(1)}_{ab}[\gamma^{(2)}_{cd}]
$$
where the last equality follows from (4.4.50). This clearly is the first term in the expression provided by Wald. As for the second term however, there is no obvious linearity of $G^{(2)}$ in the same sense as for $G^{(1)}$, as far as I can see. From equation (4.4.51), we see that the Ricci tensor consists of sums of terms of the form $\partial \gamma \partial \gamma$ and $\gamma \partial \partial \gamma$, meaning that substituting the corrected perturbation, we get mixed terms. As an example, the first term of the Ricci tensor for the new perturbation $\gamma_{ab} + \gamma^{(2)}_{ab}$ would be:
$$
\frac{1}{2}\gamma^{cd}\partial_a \partial_b \gamma_{cd} + \frac{1}{2}\gamma^{cd}\partial_a \partial_b \gamma^{(2)}_{cd} + \frac{1}{2}\gamma^{(2)cd}\partial_a \partial_b \gamma_{cd} + \frac{1}{2}\gamma^{(2)cd}\partial_a \partial_b \gamma^{(2)}_{cd}
$$
Since $G$ is essentially a sum of the Ricci tensor and its contraction, we should be able to split the sum into components in the following way:
$$
G^{(2)}_{ab}[\gamma_{cd} + \gamma^{(2)}_{cd}] = G^{(2)}_{ab}[\gamma_{cd}] + G^{(2)}_{ab}[\gamma^{(2)}_{cd}] + \text{mixed terms}
$$
where the mixed terms are mixed in $\gamma_{ab}$ and $\gamma^{(2)}_{ab}$. Consequently, from equation (1), I land at the following second order equation:
$$
G^{(1)}_{ab}[\gamma^{(2)}_{cd}] + G^{(2)}_{ab}[\gamma_{cd}] + G^{(2)}_{ab}[\gamma^{(2)}_{cd}] + \text{mixed terms} = 0
$$
Clearly this is not the same as (4.4.52). I first thought that it was implicitly assumed that $\gamma^{(2)}_{ab}$ fulfills the equation $G^{(2)}_{ab}[\gamma^{(2)}_{cd}] = 0$. However there are two issues with this. Firstly, it only gets rid of one extra term, not the mixed terms as far as I can see. Secondly, there is no mention of this condition anywhere in the book, meaning that it would have to be an implicit result from (4.4.52). Otherwise, when using (4.4.52), you would have to also solve $G^{(2)}_{ab}[\gamma^{(2)}_{cd}] = 0$.
The other thing I considered was if $\gamma_{cd}$ really meant the new perturbation, including the second order correction, i.e. $\gamma^{\text{old}}_{cd} + \gamma^{(2)}_{cd}$. However, in that case, equation (4.4.52) would be more complicated, since the second term of (4.4.52) would also depend on $\gamma_{ab}^{(2)}$. The book makes it sound like you can just find the second order Einstein tensor for your old perturbation $\gamma_{cd}$ and then use that to find the new correction, by treating it as an additional stress-energy tensor. This would not be as easy if the second term depends on the second order correction. On the other hand, this would make my derivation exactly match (4.4.52). Still, I doubt this is the case.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

The terms you describe are simply higher order in perturbation, and thus they do not yet contribute to your system. The mixed terms would be present once you go to third order, and the $G^{(2)}[\gamma^{(2)}]$ term enters at fourth order.
Also the scheme you described to generate the metric perturbatively does in fact work. This is somewhat a field theory approach. It is somewhat the same as how one finds general relativity solutions from linearized gravity.
I can add more detail if needed!

Thank you so much! You have really made things easier for me this week. Just a few questions so that I completely understand: When you talk about order, I'm assuming that you mean some sort of expansion of $g_{ab}$ in terms of a variable $\lambda$? Because $G^{(2)}$ would be quadratic in its "input perturbation" regardless right? In that case, is it true that we indirectly assume that the correction $\gamma^{(2)}{ab}$ is significantly smaller than $\gamma{ab}$? Is that why $G^{(2)}$ for the correction and the mixed terms can be ignored? Otherwise, how do I show that they are small?

yeah, that’s exactly what I mean! I usually use some book-keeping variable like $\varepsilon$ for orders of perturbation, so I’d expand the metric to $N^{th}$ order as $g=\sum_{i=0}^N \varepsilon^i \gamma^{(i)}$, where $\gamma^{(0)}$ is taken to be Minkowski if we’re perturbing around flat-space, though you could use another background metric like Schwarzschild. Then just input this into the Einstein field equations and do a series expansion around $\varepsilon=0$. Quantities entering at $\mathcal O(\varepsilon^n)$ are then the order $n$ perturbation equations.

Also you are correct about the scaling. You can think of it like taking $\varepsilon$ to denote smallness, so higher orders in $\varepsilon$ are smaller than lower orders in epsilon. This gives $\gamma^{(1)} \gg \gamma^{(2)}$, as you’ve indicated. I just also emphasize you can take $\varepsilon=1$ as long as you keep in mind how perturbative functions scale with respect to each other, but it’s convenient to have this book-keeping parameter in order to see explicitly how things things enter perturbatively.
